# Multiply 2 palindromic alphametics to make a pandigital number

Tags: no-computers, alphametic, palindrome

There are some different definitions of pandigital numbers, so
to avoid misinterpretation, lets use this definition:

> **Pandigital numbers (pandigit) are numbers containing the digits 0-9, where each digit appears exactly once:**

An example would be $3421567890$.

Solve this

```
Alphametic Palindrome :    ABCBA
Alphametic Palindrome :  x CBABC
                           -----
Non Alphametic        : pandigit
```

Comment: i dont get the question

Comment: @lois6b: Determine the single digits `A`, `B` and `C` such that the product  `ABCBA * CBABC` is a pandigital number, i.e. digit permutaion of `9876543210`.

Comment: and what is alphametric?

Comment: @lois6b read the tag description, if still confuse, see the questions with the tag, I hope you will understand

Comment: @lois6b: An alphametic is a calculation in the form `SEND + MORE = MONEY`, where each letter represents one of the digits uniquely. You'll end up thinking about end digits of multiplications and carry-overs a lot. But here, alphametic is just used to explain which digits in the two factors are the same.

Comment: oh i see, sorry hehe is very early in  the morning

Comment: @lois6b, even though the computerized answer has been accepted, if you are the first to solve this analytically you are likely to get more votes than that answer. (Doesn't look like you need votes though.)

Comment: @humn i dont know how. i wanted an answer without computers to learn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, this was easy:

> 18981*98189 = 1863725409 (or the other way around: 98189*18981 = 1863725409)

There were really not much to do here, as you have had a search space of only (roughly) 729 cases.

Comment: can you explain the process you followed?

Comment: it says, no-computers. I'm sure you used a computer for this. The question was posted 50 minutes before your answer. Let's say it took you 5 minutes to read the question, think of a strategy and write the answer. So 45 minutes to find it. This means you checked one solution each 3.7 seconds. I don't think that's possible without computers. Boom. math-lawyer-ed. http://s2.quickmeme.com/img/49/493b3b31e703be94eace17763afd160124407f1450556e7c20c9105c258fd675.jpg

Comment: At least computerized answers can help verify uniqueness.  Thank you for that.

Comment: And there are 576 possible combinations. This means one check for every 4.6s. Still not realistic.

Comment: i liked the no-computers tag to know ways to answer this analytically ..

Comment: Analysis without a computer can give you a rough idea of the range the 5-digit numbers would have to be in, to give a 10-digit product, and modular arithmetic considerations can reduce the search space a bit, but there are still so many cases that a computer program is still the best tool for the job.

Answer (score 7):

Partial solution

> As the sum of digits 0+1+...+9 is divisible by 9, every pandigital number is divisible by 9.
>  So the pandigital product is divisible by 9, which means that either
>  1. both terms `ABCBA` and `CBABC` are divisible by 3
>  or
>  2. one of the terms is divisible by 9.

Case 1

> This means, `A+B+C+B+A` is divisible by 3 and `C+B+A+B+C` is divisible by 3. As a consequence, their difference, `A-C` is also divisible by 3.
>  So `A+C+A` and `C+A+C` will be divisible by 3, so `B+B` has to be divisible by 3 too, which means, `B` is divisible by 3.
>  Without loss of generality we can suppose `A>C`.
>  As `A`, `B` and `C` have to be distinct, `A>=3+C`. Also, `A` and `C` cannot be 0 as they are leading digits of the terms.
>  So `A` can have 6 values (anything greater than 3), `C` at most 2 (larger than 0, less than A, but same residual modulo 3), `B` at most 4 (divisible by 3).
>  That's at most 48 cases to check (actually 30, if you cut all the estimations).

Case 2

> Without loss of generality, we can suppose `ABCBA` is the one which is divisible by 9.
>  `A` can be any non-zero digit, that's 9 different values. `B` can be anything different (even 0), that's another 9. The value of `C` is determined, as it cannot be 0 (its the leading digit of the other term), but has to make the sum divisible by 9.
>  That's another 81 cases to check.

Comment: in the case 1, why "A-C is also divisible by 3." ?

Comment: @loisb The difference of two numbers which are divisible by 3 is also divisible by 3.

Comment: oh wait, i see what you meant, the difference between A+B+C+B+A and C+B+A+B+C. i understood the difference A-C

Comment: @loisb, (A+B+C+B+A)-(C+B+A+B+C)=A-C

Answer (score 4):

I boiled down to 140 + 47 (unique) tests.

I found two answers that validate the equation for any A, B and C, but only one is alphametic:

> A = 1, B = 8, C = 9 : 18981 x 98189 = 1863725409

The non-alphametic answer to the equation is

> A = 6, B = 9, C = 9 : 69996 x 99699 = 6978531204
>  Not alphametic because B = C (or B = A).

I based myself on the answer of @elias and brute-forced my handy way from there.

> ```
>          ABCBA
>        x CBABC
>     ----------
>     QRSTUVWXYZ
>
>     Rules:
>     * Q+R+S+T+U+V+W+X+Y+Z mod 9 = 0
>     * (A+1)*(C+1)100000000 >= 1023456789 (technically equivalent to (A+1)(C+1) > 10)).
>     * A can't be 0, C can't be 0.
>
>     First case as defined by @elias (140 tests, 1 solution):
>     => (ABCBA % 3 == 0 && CBABC % 3 == 0) || (ABCBA % 9 == 0 || CBABC % 9 == 0)
>
>     If ABCBA % 3 == 0 && CBABC % 3 == 0
>
>       Since A and C can be switched, I arbitrarily decide that A <= C.
>
>       -> A-C % 3 == 0
>          => A, C are both among [1,4,7] Fail: all cases below
>             => A = 1 Fail: all cases below
>                => C = 1 Fail: (A+1)*(C+1)100000000 < 1023456789
>                => C = 4 Fail: (A+1)(C+1)*100000000 < 1023456789
>                => C = 7 Fail: no value of B gives a pandigital number as result
>             => A = 4 Fail: all cases below
>                => C = 4 Fail: no value of B gives a pandigital number as result
>                => C = 7 Fail: no value of B gives a pandigital number as result
>             => A = 7 Fail: all cases below
>                => C = 7 Fail: no value of B gives a pandigital number as result
>
>
>          => A, C are both among [2,5,8] Fail: all cases below
>             => A = 2 Fail: all cases below
>                => C = 2 Fail: (A+1)(C+1)*100000000 < 1023456789
>                => C = 5 Fail: no value of B gives a pandigital number as result
>                => C = 8 Fail: no value of B gives a pandigital number as result
>             => A = 5 Fail: all cases below
>                => C = 5 Fail: no value of B gives a pandigital number as result
>                => C = 8 Fail: no value of B gives a pandigital number as result
>
>          => A, C are both among [3,6,9] One solution
>             => A = 3 Fail: all cases below
>                => C = 3 Fail: no value of B gives a pandigital number as result
>                => C = 6 Fail: no value of B gives a pandigital number as result
>                => C = 9 Fail: no value of B gives a pandigital number as result
>             => A = 6: One solution
>                => C = 6 Fail: no value of B gives a pandigital number as result
>                => C = 9 Solution for B = 9 => 69996 x 99699 = 6978531204
>             => A = 9: Fail: all cases below
>                => C = 9 Fail: no value of B gives a pandigital number as result
>
>     Second case as defined by @elias (88 tests, 1 solution)
>     Else ABCBA % 9 == 0 || CBABC % 9 == 0
>
>       Since A and C can be switched, I arbitrarily decide that ABCBA % 9 == 0.
>
>       => A+B+C+B+A % 9 == 0
>         B = (27 - 2 * A - C) / 2 % 9 or (36 - 2 * A - C) / 2 % 9, whichever is integer.
>         For a fixed A, increasing C, B appears in the following sequence: 1, 5, (0 or 9), 4, 8, 3, 7, 2, 6, 1, 5, etc.
>         All values where B is one of 0, 3, 6, 9 means that we're back to A - C % 3 = 0 and have already been tested.
>           So there are 88 total tests, but 47 that are not duplicates from the first case.
>
>         => A = 1 One solution
>            => C < 5 Fail: (A+1)*(C+1)*100000000 < 1023456789
>            => C = 5 => B = 1 Fail: result is not pandigital
>            => C = 6 => B = 5 Fail: result is not pandigital
>            => C = 7 => B = 0 or 9 Already tested
>            => C = 8 => B = 4 Fail: result is not pandigital
>            => C = 9 => B = 8 OK: 18981*98189 = 1863725409
>         => A = 2 Fail: all cases below
>            => C < 4 Fail: (A+1)*(C+1)100000000 < 1023456789
>            => C = 4 => B = 5 Fail: result is not pandigital
>            => C = 5 => B = 0 or 9 Already tested
>            => C = 6 => B = 4 Fail: result is not pandigital
>            => C = 7 => B = 8 Fail: result is not pandigital
>            => C = 8 => B = 3 Already tested
>            => C = 9 => B = 7 Fail: result is not pandigital
>         => A = 3 Fail: all cases below
>            => C < 3 Fail: (A+1)(C+1)100000000 < 1023456789
>            => C = 3 => B = 0 or 9  Fail: results are not pandigital
>            => C = 4 => B = 4 Fail: result is not pandigital
>            => C = 5 => B = 8 Fail: result is not pandigital
>            => C = 6 => B = 3 Already tested
>            => C = 7 => B = 7 Fail: result is not pandigital
>            => C = 8 => B = 2 Fail: result is not pandigital
>            => C = 9 => B = 6 Already tested (already tested in first case)
>         => A = 4 Fail: all cases below
>            => C = 1 Fail: (A+1)(C+1)100000000 < 1023456789
>            => C = 2 => B = 4 Fail: result is not pandigital
>            => C = 3 => B = 8 Fail: result is not pandigital
>            => C = 4 => B = 3 Already tested
>            => C = 5 => B = 7 Fail: result is not pandigital
>            => C = 6 => B = 2 Fail: result is not pandigital
>            => C = 7 => B = 6 Already tested
>            => C = 8 => B = 1 Fail: result is not pandigital
>            => C = 9 => B = 5 Fail: result is not pandigital
>         => A = 5 Fail: all cases below
>            => C = 1 Fail: (A+1)(C+1)*100000000 < 1023456789
>            => C = 2 => B = 3 Already tested
>            => C = 3 => B = 7 Fail: result is not pandigital
>            => C = 4 => B = 2 Fail: result is not pandigital
>            => C = 5 => B = 6 Already tested
>            => C = 6 => B = 1 Fail: result is not pandigital
>            => C = 7 => B = 5 Fail: result is not pandigital
>            => C = 8 => B = 0 or 9 Already tested
>            => C = 9 => B = 4 Fail: result is not pandigital
>         => A = 6 Fail: all cases below
>            => C = 1 => B = 7 Fail: result is not pandigital
>            => C = 2 => B = 2 Fail: result is not pandigital
>            => C = 3 => B = 6 Already tested
>            => C = 4 => B = 1 Fail: result is not pandigital
>            => C = 5 => B = 5 Fail: result is not pandigital
>            => C = 6 => B = 0 or 9 Already tested
>            => C = 7 => B = 4 Fail: result is not pandigital
>            => C = 8 => B = 8 Fail: result is not pandigital
>            => C = 9 => B = 3 Already tested
>         => A = 7 Fail: all cases below
>            => C = 1 => B = 6 Already tested
>            => C = 2 => B = 1 Fail: result is not pandigital
>            => C = 3 => B = 5 Fail: result is not pandigital
>            => C = 4 => B = 0 or 9 Already tested
>            => C = 5 => B = 4 Fail: result is not pandigital
>            => C = 6 => B = 8 Fail: result is not pandigital
>            => C = 7 => B = 3 Already tested
>            => C = 8 => B = 7 Fail: result is not pandigital
>            => C = 9 => B = 2 Fail: result is not pandigital
>         => A = 8 Fail: all cases below
>            => C = 1 => B = 5 Fail: result is not pandigital
>            => C = 2 => B = 0 or 9 Already tested
>            => C = 3 => B = 4 Fail: result is not pandigital
>            => C = 4 => B = 8 Fail: result is not pandigital
>            => C = 5 => B = 3 Already tested
>            => C = 6 => B = 7 Fail: result is not pandigital
>            => C = 7 => B = 2 Fail: result is not pandigital
>            => C = 8 => B = 6 Already tested
>            => C = 9 => B = 1 Fail: result is not pandigital
>         => A = 9 Fail: all cases below
>            => C = 1 => B = 4 Fail: result is not pandigital
>            => C = 2 => B = 8 Fail: result is not pandigital
>            => C = 3 => B = 3 Already tested
>            => C = 4 => B = 7 Fail: result is not pandigital
>            => C = 5 => B = 2 Fail: result is not pandigital
>            => C = 6 => B = 6 Already tested
>            => C = 7 => B = 1 Fail: result is not pandigital
>            => C = 8 => B = 5 Fail: result is not pandigital
>            => C = 9 => B = 0 or 9 Already tested
> ```

Comment: If anyone knows how to write code in spoilers, I'd appreciate you to edit my answer to do so. Thanks!

Comment: "Nothing stated anywhere that two distinct letters couldn't represent the same digit.". Usually Alphametic means that different letters mean different digits.

Comment: @Marius Both the tag and the question don't explicitly mention this. I double-checked before answering. The question is above, the tag only says: "Alphametic puzzles involve equations where numbers have been replaced with letters."

Comment: @Marius Damn, I see the rule now, it's written when you click on the tag then again on "learn more". Kind of hard to get to that rule, though... Should I delete the answer?

Comment: I don't think you should delete it. It's a quality answer. Maybe you can just refine it a bit to ignore the cases when 2 letters represent the same digit. But definitely DO NOT delete it.

Comment: Ok, I took that into account and edited my answer.